# Should I use Prepared Statement for inserting one row?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I just found that there are places in our code that use Prepared Statement even though we always deal with inserting one row to the table.

I'm wondering if using Prepared Statement when only inserting one row has some overhead that worth modifying this code to use Statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16760724/285587

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use PreparedStement, not just your query execution is faster there are other advantages too.

- You queries **execute fast** as PreparedStatement results into the query being precompiled on the database and reused.
- PreparedStatement, your **queries are dynamic**. Meaning, you define the query only once, and reuse the same again with different parameters. String  concatenation also achieves it but its crude way doing this. Quoting [this link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)

> The important thing to remember is to never construct SQL statements
>   using string concatenation of unchecked input values. Creating of
>   dynamic queries via the java.sql.Statement class leads to SQL
>   Injection.

- When you use PreparedStatement you [**prevent** the **SQL injection attacks**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java).  In Prepared statement, you do not use string concatenation for adding the runtime parameters but instead set the parameter explicitly in the compiled query and the **parameters passed are escaped** automatically by JDBC Driver for PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 2):

On the security side, `Prepared Statements` are used especially to prevent SQL Injection attacks. About efficiency, it very much depends on the nature of the statement you are dealing with. You may also find interesting this other answer:

[Why PreparedStatement is preferable over Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717355/why-preparedstatement-is-preferable-over-statement/10717575#10717575)

Answer (score 1):

A `PreparedStatement` is prefrable to a simple `Statement` as it offes your some security against SQL injection.

In a `PreparedStatement` every parameter is checked for its type and automatically escaped. This means that inserting `String` with an `'` is save with `PreparedStatement` whereas you have to escape special characters yourself when not using a `PreparedStatement`.

Also you cannot insert some `String` where a `Number` is expected.

Answer (score 0):

If even your code inserts only one row it may be called many times in which case `PreparedStatement` is supposed to be faster. As for `Statement` it also needs to be compiled before execution so it's hardly be any faster